# Python stacked barchart where y-axis scale is linear but the bar fill is logarithmic in the order of 10s

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

As the title explains, I am trying to reproduce a stacked barchart where the y-axis scale is linear but the inside fill of the plot (i.e. the stacked bars) are logarithmic and grouped in the order of 10s.

I have made this plot before on R-Studio with an in-house package, however I am trying to reproduce the plot with other programs (python) to validate and confirm my analysis.

**Quick description of the data w/ more detail:**

I have thousands of entries of clonal cell information. They have multiple identifiers, such as "Strain", "Sample", "cloneID", as well as a frequency value ("cloneFraction") for each clone.

[This is the .head() of the dataset I am working with to give you an idea of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnQ5Q.png)

I am trying to reproduce this following plot I made with R-Studio:
[this one here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJhYw.png)

This plot has the dataset divided in groups based on their frequency, with the top 10 most frequent grouped in red, followed by the next top 100, next 1000, etc etc. The y-axis has a 0.00-1.00 scale but also a 100% scale wouldn't change, they mean the same thing in this context.

This is just to get an idea and visualize if I have big clones (the top 10) and how much of the overall dataset they occupy in frequency - i.e. the bigger the red stack the larger clones I have, signifying there has been a significant clonal expansion in my sample of a few selected cells.

**What I have done so far:**

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
%matplotlib inline

MYDATAFRAME.groupby(['Sample','cloneFraction']).size().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 100 * x / x.sum()).unstack().plot(kind='bar',stacked=True, legend=None)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
plt.show()
```

[And I get this plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdSdq.png)

Now, I realize there is no order in the stacked plot, so the most frequent aren't on top - it's just stacking in the order of the entries in my dataset (which I assume I can just fix by sorting my dataframe by the column of interest).

Other than the axis messing up and not giving my a % when I use log scale (which is a secondary issue), I can't seem/wouldn't know how to group the data entries by frequency as I mentioned above.

I have tried things such as:

```
temp = X.SOME_IDENTIFIER.value_counts()
temp2 = temp.head(10)
if len(temp) > 10:
    temp2['remaining {0} items'.format(len(temp) - 10)] = sum(temp[10:])
temp2.plot(kind='pie')
```

Just to see if I could separate them in a correct way but this does not achieve what I would like (other than being a pie chart, but I changed that in my code).

I have also tried using iloc[n:n] to select specific entries, but I can't seem to get that working either, as I get errors when I try adding it to the code I've used above to plot my graph - and if I use it without the other fancy stuff in the code (% scale, etc) it gets confused in the stacked barplot and just plots the top 10 out of all the 4 samples in my data, rather than the top 10 **per** sample. I also wouldn't know how to get the next 100, 1000, etc.

If you have any suggestions and can help in any way, that would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed what I wanted to do with the following:

I created a new column with the category my samples fall in, base on their value (i.e. if they're the top 10 most frequent, next 100, etc etc).

```
df['category']='10001+'

for sampleref in df.sample_ref.unique().tolist():

print(f'Setting sample {sampleref}')

df.loc[df[df.sample_ref == sampleref].nlargest(10000, 'cloneCount')['category'].index,'category']='1001-10000'

df.loc[df[df.sample_ref == sampleref].nlargest(1000, 'cloneCount')['category'].index,'category']='101-1000'

df.loc[df[df.sample_ref == sampleref].nlargest(100, 'cloneCount')['category'].index,'category']='11-100'

df.loc[df[df.sample_ref == sampleref].nlargest(10, 'cloneCount')['category'].index,'category']='top10'
```

This code starts from the biggest group (10001+) and goes smaller and smaller, to include overlapping samples that might fall into the next big group.

Following this, I plotted the samples with the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))


df.groupby(['Sample','category']).sum()['cloneFraction'].unstack().plot(ax=ax, kind="bar", stacked=True)


plt.xticks(rotation=0)

plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter(1))

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[::-1], labels[::-1], title='Clonotype',bbox_to_anchor=(1.04,0), loc="lower left", borderaxespad=0)
```

**And here are the results:**
[image: Here]

I hope this helps anyone struggling with the same issue!